# VTK VisualStudio2013 Compile Error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, vtk

I'm trying to compile VTK5.10.1 in windows7 and Visual Studio2013( vs2012 C++ compiler, so I guess somebody may face the same question in 2012)

After fix some small bug and some missing head file 
Follow the tuitols of the VTK wiki. IN THE LAST STEP:

I got two error

1. C2678: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::ostream' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

> #define VTKOSTREAM_OPERATOR(type) \   vtkOStreamWrapper&
>   vtkOStreamWrapper::operator << (type a) \
>       { this->ostr << a; return *this; }
>
> ```
> VTKOSTREAM_OPERATOR(ostream&);
> ```

2.binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::basic_istream>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

> ```
>  if ( this->IFile->read(result, 80) == 0)
> ```

Here the source code tray to run operator== between std :: basic_istream> and int

But int the std::istream the operator== is not override.

Waiting for help.
Thanks

Comment: vtk 5.10.1 compiles and executes fine (well at lest the parts I use) for me under Visual Studio 2012. I do not have access to Visual Studio 2013 pro yet so I have not tested that. Did you try using the V110 toolset when generating for VS12 (Visual Studio 2013).

Comment: I have fix the second bug. std::basic_istream is inherit from std:base_istream and have override operator! to confirm the I/O function is running without error

Comment: @drescherjm  Thanks, I just want to change the toolset but I have only two choice V120 for vs2013 and v100 for vs2010... ...I got no idea why i can't use v110

Comment: Those are both the native toolsets. I am not sure why it is not picking up V110.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've got exactly the same errors when building VTK 5.8.0 in Win 8.1 + VS2013x64.

Here's my solution:

1. After substituting the macros, the error goes to the definition of `operator<<`. The compiler need to find an declaration that matches

   ```
   this->ostr << a;
   ```

   where the type of `this->ostr` and `a` are both `std::ostream &`. So I wrote a simple test code to check the VS compiler.

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <sstream>

   void test(std::ostream &a, std::ostream &b) {
       a << b;
   }

   int main(int argc, char *argv[])
   {
       std::ostringstream a,b;
       test(a,b);
       std::cout << a << std::endl;
       return 0;
   }
   ```

   It turns out to be correct on GCC4.7. And seems that `ostream` is auto-casted to some kind of a pointer (not its own address, but it doesn't matter, just output an address). However, VS2013 gives me the same error as building VTK! So, let's make rewrite the definition of `vtkOStreamWrapper::operator<< (ostream &a)`:

   ```
   //VTKOSTREAM_OPERATOR(ostream&);
   vtkOStreamWrapper& vtkOStreamWrapper::operator << (ostream& a) {
       this->ostr << (void *)&a;
       return *this;
   }
   ```
2. Since the code

   ```
   if ( this->IFile->read(result, 80) == 0)
   ```

   actually is a C++11 way to determine whether `ifstream->read()` suceeds or not (a `ostream` can be auto-casted to a `bool`), which is not supported by VS2013. I change all of them into standard form:

   ```
   if ( this->IFile->read(result, 80).fail())
   ```

Comment: I had to resolve some C2039 errors with inserting `#include <algorithm>` in the respective files.

Comment: The same solution, `#include <algorithm>` for the C3861 errors that occurred when compiling with parallel support.